# NHibernate count average on select

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

first of all, I am new to NHibernate. Here is my problem:

I have data stored in Database, and each sample in DB has attribute Date and numeric value. Now I would like to know, is there any way, that I can SELECT some data and count an average (of numeric values) in each 3 second interval ?

I am using QueryOver.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple group by. But I do not use [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover). Try converting following [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) query:

```
var test = session.Query<Entity>()
    .GroupBy(e => 
        new
        {
            e.YourDate.Date,
            e.YourDate.Hour,
            e.YourDate.Minute,
            threeSec = e.YourDate.Second / 3
        })
    .Select(g =>
        new {
            g.Key.Date,
            g.Key.Hour,
            g.Key.Minute,
            g.Key.threeSec,
            avg = g.Average(e => e.YourNumeric)
        })
    .ToList();
```

On a big dataset, it may perform poorly. The server will be unlikely to use an index on such a group by.